# FATAL exception main (RuntimeException)

Tags: java, android, sdk

There are no errors in the source (osmand)

I used  eclipse and sdk emulator 2.2  checkout from googlecode 
(osmand application)

My code :

```
public void onCreate(){ 
    super.onCreate(); 
    routingHelper = new RoutingHelper(OsmandSettings.getApplicationMode(OsmandSettings.getPrefs(OsmandAp­plication.this)), OsmandApplication.this, player); 
    manager = new ResourceManager(this); 
    daynightHelper = new DayNightHelper(this); 
    uiHandler = new Handler(); 
    startApplication(); 
}
```

These are all errors in logcat :

```
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): FATAL EXCEPTION:     main 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application net.osmand.activities.OsmandApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream can not be null 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): Has android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java: 4247) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): Has android.app.ActivityThread.access $ 3000 (ActivityThread.java: 125) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): at $ android.app.ActivityThread H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java: 2071) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): Has android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java: 99) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): Has android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java: 123) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): Has android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java: 4627) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR / AndroidRuntime (308): Has java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:185) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.OsmandRenderingRulesParser.parseRenderingRules(OsmandRend­eringRulesParser.java: 104) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.BaseOsmandRender.init(BaseOsmandRender.java:41) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.RendererRegistry.loadRenderer(RendererRegistry.java: 116) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.RendererRegistry.loadRenderer(RendererRegistry.java: 103) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.RendererRegistry.getRenderer(RendererRegistry.java: 93) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.RendererRegistry.getRenderer(RendererRegistry.java: 84) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.RendererRegistry.defaultRender(RendererRegistry.java: 54) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.OsmandRenderer.<init>(OsmandRenderer.java:239) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.MapRenderRepositories.<init>(MapRenderRepositories.java: 79) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.ResourceManager.<init>(ResourceManager.java:98) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.activities.OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java: 51) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 969) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4244) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: show the code of onCreate() of osmandApplication, please.

Comment: Hi loto, you should be more descriptive in your questions if you want to receive useful help : post the full stacktrace, post the code that is throwing the exception, try having a more descriptive-related title to your question !

Comment: could you add the code of : OsmandApplication.java I think this is the file sending the error. (OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java: 51) )

Comment: public void onCreate(){
     super.onCreate();
     routingHelper = new RoutingHelper(OsmandSettings.getApplicationMode(OsmandSettings.getPrefs(OsmandApplication.this)), OsmandApplication.this, player);
     manager = new ResourceManager(this);
     daynightHelper = new DayNightHelper(this);
     uiHandler = new Handler();
     startApplication();
 }

Comment: public ResourceManager getResourceManager() {
  return manager;
 }

Comment: ResourceManager manager = null;

Answer (score 1):

At runtime (execution time) you pass a `null` value to some method that expects/requires an instance of `InputStream` (or any subclass). This kind of error can't be detected by a compiler and therefore your source compiles.

To debug: find that line of code in your sources that causes that runtime exception. At that line you'll find some `InputStream` variable and you have to analyse the source to answer *why* and *under which conditions* the variable holds `null` instead of a stream reference.

---

From your stacktrace I see that those three lines give a hint to the problem:

```
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:185) 
05-04 07:53:01.807: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(308):at net.osmand.render.OsmandRenderingRulesParser.parseRenderingRules(OsmandRend­eringRulesParser.java: 104)
```

The application tries to open a xml file (the name is unknown from the log) and this xml can't be found by the application.

So you have to find out, *which* file is needed (the file should contain some sort of *rendering rules*) and *where* it has to stored for the application to find it. The error is gone as soon as the parser can load the missing file.

Comment: but InputStream is class not variable   java.io.inputstream

Comment: ... some *variable that is defined as `InputStream` or a subclass`*

Comment: i need more help please i am realy all traying